# Fixed background zooms on mobile when scrollling

Tags: css, reactjs, responsive-design

when I open my app on my mobile and I scroll down it zooms a little and if I come back to the top of the page it resizes back to normal.

That happens for both Home and About pages. On devTools nothing wrong but as I said on mobile phone it gives this problem.

I set the background to `cover` and position `center center` but nothing changed.

```
.main-home {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)),
    url('./Images/adils-photography-gmo6Ok9G0U8-unsplash.jpg');
  
  z-index: -1;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center center;
  height: 95vh;
}
```

Here's the app url: https://restaurant-finder-123.netlify.app/
and it's repository: https://github.com/mugg84/RestaurantFinder.git

Thanks for your help

Comment: I thought it may be a CSS issue with viewport size and your responsive design. What mobile browsers (and versions) have you tested on and reproduced this issue?

Comment: @DrewReese I tried on two different phones both using Chrome. One Version 84.0.4147.89 the other one 83.0.4103.106

Answer (score 0):

Try adding 'user-scalable=0' in your html meta tag

Like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=0" />
```

Comment: Nope, it's still giving the same issue